# How to get the list of notebooks that are automatically opened when Mathematica starts?

Tags: notebooks

How to get the list of notebooks that are automatically opened when Mathematica starts programmatically?  I know a tedious approach is opening option inspector and finding and copying the list out.

Comment: `Options[$FrontEnd]` gives you the same info as the option inspector.  But I always thought that Mathematica will only auto-open notebooks on OS X, and that's an OS X feature, not a Mathematica feature.  (I might be wrong.)

Comment: @Szabolcs I think you are right. It has never automatically opened notebooks for me on Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 8):

```
Options[$FrontEnd, AutoOpenNotebooks]
```

or

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, AutoOpenNotebooks]
```

Comment: I corrected this to work even if the option is not explicitly set.